# How to detect if flutter website is running in the background of browser?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

WidgetsBindingObserver is not working on my flutter web project. Is there something similar to detect when the user closes the browser like closing on the native device app with widgetbinding?

I want to rebuild the whole website after every time the browser was rebuilt regardless if the website was left open before.

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to this question?

Answer (score 3):

Hook into the browser's visibility change API.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

  // inside your State class

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChange);
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  void onVisibilityChange(Event e) {
    // do something
  }
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

Comment: _This_ is the answer; works a treat.
The linter is going to scream at the use of dart:html outside a web plugin, so either try that or wrap the relevant code in a platform check and pull the rule