# Flutter Web: How to detect AppLifeCycleState changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I tested out the `AppLifeCycleState` on flutter web and it didn't work while it worked on mobile platforms.

This is an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53107) that is being worked on.

**I was wondering if anyone knew any workarounds or packages which could do this?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is my workaround

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

  // inside your State class

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (kIsWeb) {
      window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
      window.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
    } else {
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      window.removeEventListener('focus', onFocus);
      window.removeEventListener('blur', onBlur);
    } else {
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onFocus(Event e) {
    didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState.resumed);
  }

  void onBlur(Event e) {
    didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState.paused);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    // do your thing
  }
```

Basically you hook into the browser's visibility API and invoke the life cycle callback yourself.

See also [How to detect if flutter website is running in the background of browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64550286/how-to-detect-if-flutter-website-is-running-in-the-background-of-browser/66506188#66506188)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. What is the `onVisbilityChange`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't extend the class with `WidgetsBindingObserver` the errors are gone. I'll test it now.

Comment: Hello, this works if I change tabs, is there a way I can also update the app life cycle state when the browser is out of focus? Thanks!

Comment: Just like above but you hook into the browser's [focus API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus_event) instead

Comment: May you please provide a code example? I tried doing it but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Also, in the code above, the code doesn't dispose properly and `didChangeAppLifecycleState()` still runs.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Also, yes this is a [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69949) with flutter hot restart.

Comment: Do I replace the `window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', onVisibilityChange);` with what you edited in your answer? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Calling the dispose method normally (by popping the route) still doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, as I commented in the github issue, the best I can do is to make the listeners static, and then it does work. Let me know if you find a better way.

Comment: Where do you add the static modifier?

Comment: `static void onFocus(Event e) { ... }`. The catch is you can't call didChangeAppLifecycleState now because that's non-static. You'll have to work around that

Comment: Oh ok thanks. I worked around the dispose not working by making a Boolean variable and then in the `onFocus()` and `onBlur()` I add an `if` check. It looks something like `if (active) {...}`. That seemed to fix the problem for me without having to make the methods static so that I don't have to work around the problem of not being able to call `didChangeAppLifecycleState`. That seemed to fix the dispose issue but also works when hot restarting. I think it's a better fix than the static with the only problem being that it leaks memory and might not be very performant on larger scale apps.